# Как с javascript перейти на другую страницу на стороннем сайте

Tags: javascript

Я нахожусь на одном сайте, и мне надо перейти по ссылке на другой. Но проблема в том, что я не могу понять, когда другой сайт полностью прогрузится, к тому же после перехода на другую страницу с помощью изменения `document.location` сам `document` всё равно ссылается на старый сайт, я никак не могу взаимодействовать с открывшейся страницей даже после ее полной прогрузки. Я пробовал `document.addEventListener`, `document.readyState`, но `document`, как я написал ранее, относится к первой странице и код просто не выполняется.
Пишу в консоли Firefox

Comment: У вас так не получится. Вы переходите на другой сайт и не можете исполнять там скрипты с другого сайта.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko можно использовать https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru

Comment: @doox911 я не говорил про расширения.